# Vue component changing its own property in store

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

okay, it's a little hard to explain, but i'll try.

i have some components rendered in a loop from an array of cards in my vuex store

```
<card-base
        v-for="(card, i) in cards"
        :class="`dashboard-card ${card.hidden ? 'hidden' : ''}`">
```

note the class depending on `card.hidden`, which is **false** onload

now, every `<card-base>` has a button (hide), which is supposed to.. well, hide it.

the way i try to do that is:
a v-btn in the card-base component gets a `@click`property, which calls a method.

### The Problem / Question

now i want to set the `hidden` property of the clicked card to true.

of course

```
  minimizeDashboardCard() {
    console.log(this.hidden)
    this.hidden = true
  }
```

doesn't work, because `this` is not the actual object from vuex, which provides the reactive properties, but just the "element".
if i set `this.hidden = true`, nothing changes (except the console.log correctly showing "true" after the first click)

but how can i access the actual vuex object from `this`? how do i get the *index* which i want to edit in my array? is there a way to have the card component "say" something like:

"dispatch an action that changes **ME** in the actual vuex array"?

like `dispatch('hideCard', this)` and have it actually working?

### TLDR

**how can i find out the index of the clicked card in the array, or directly target it in any other way? is there a connection between a rendered element and the array in store which defines it?**

i hope you understood my problem :D
thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your code? I do not use vuex but isn't `this` supposed to always refer to the vue environment of the entire component as long as you use it in the root of your methods? Plus, during your loop you can easily attach the index of the rendered card thru something like `:idx="i"`

Comment: The click handler call of a card passes the card's index (`i`) along, the handler function changes array element [i]. Create a [mcve] if possible.

Comment: @ChrisG so you'd do `@click="hideCard(i)"`? does the element not have any other connection to its source structure?

Comment: Even if it did, why care when `hideCard(i)` does the job? If each card is an instance, you can maybe add a prototype function hideSelf() and call that, then change the array from there. But I don't see the benefit. It's just an extra step.

Comment: i'm worried it's gonna break when i add things like sorting or elements get added/removed on the fly from an API. it just "feels" more robust if an element always knew "which one" it is.

Comment: @devman If you don't directly modify the DOM with your *sorting or elements get added/removed on the fly* but still rely on Vue's reactivity instead, you won't have problems using the indices Vue will assign during v-for; even if you sort, slice, add and remove cards on runtime, it's not gonna break at all.

Comment: If the underlying data changes (i.e. you modify or sort the array that ultimately creates these elements), then elements themselves will change too (Vue is basically going to re-render that whole list (I'm ignoring the technical/performance details, of course)).  But if you don't trust it, you can always assign some sort of unique ID property to every card and manipulate them based on those... but if you're modifying the underlying data and letting Vue/Vuex do its thing, I don't think you'll have a problem.

Comment: @MikeB. Ehhhh Vue's re-rendering mechanism is pretty darn optimized. I had no problems re-rendering elements that would otherwise take a long time if I did it using vanilla.

Comment: @AbanaClara - Yeah, I'm not saying it's not.  I'm saying that from a logical point of view it's going to "re-render" the whole list for any change, so the IDs and indexes should match up.  I know it's _actually_ going to use the shadow DOM and all that fun stuff so it only has to make a minimum number of changes - those are the technical/performance details I was ignoring for the sake of getting the other point across.  :)

Comment: ok then, thanks guys. so i understand i don't have to be worried at all, as long as i only modify reactive sources. that way, everything will be updated and stay correct. that solves my problem and i'll just use `hideCard(i)`. thanks :)
you can write an answer if you want